# iOS mapview with searchbar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

I'm totally blind about `iOS` `MapView`, here i need to know how can i show the places related to the word entered by the user in `UISearch` bar. If he types **HOSPITALS IN CHENNAI** then `MapView` has to show **MULTIPLE PINS IN MAPVIEW** under the hospitals near chennai, i have read [this link does only using the **GOOGLE ALLOWED KEYWORDS**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13160/using-the-google-places-api-with-mapkit)

I want to do like above mentioned stuff.. Please guide me.

Comment: try foursquare api https://foursquare.com/explore?near=Chennai%2C%20IN&q=HOSPITALS%20IN%20CHENNAI%20

Comment: how could i use them laxonline..?

Comment: create developer api account & follow the steps https://foursquare.com/developers/apps

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest you to use foursquare api :

https://foursquare.com/explore?near=Chennai%2C%20IN&q=HOSPITALS%20IN%20CHENNAI%20